# Derivative of the integral of composite functions?

Tags: integration, derivatives

$L=\int f(g(x))dx$ , what is $\dfrac{dL}{dg(x)}$?

Thanks in advance.

---

A note to myself: [Antiderivatives / Indefinite Integrals](http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/4/antider.1/), [Integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), [Inverse functions and differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $g(x)$ is an invertible function, so that the function $x(g)$ is well-defined.  Then can apply a change of variables to the integral: 
$$
L = \int f(g) \frac{dg}{g'(x(g))} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{dL}{dg} = \frac{f(g)}{g'(x(g))}.  
$$
If you want this in terms of $x$, it would be $f(g(x))/g'(x)$.